# weird font size setting in different apps and random places

Tags: 14.04, fonts, gtk, evolution, bluefish

ever since the update from 13.10 to 14.04 i have a font-size issue.

for example. With Evolution email the email will show in extremely large font-size (~18px)
while the folders and menu's are displayed in normal font-size

The same goes for Bluefish, directory and menu are displayed in normal font-size, while the edited file is displayed in extremely small font-size (< 6px)

Today i noticed a similar behavior in Mysql workbench. here the menu is displayed in extremely small font-size, while models and shortcuts are displayed normal.

i believe the only common item here is GTK. does anybody have a solution for this? or can confirm this!